# S6E08 what was it that Cersei and Qyburn talked about?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In episode 8 of season 6 there was a scene with Cersei and Qyburn after king Tommen's speech. They talked about "some rumor" and about how the birds say it's much more than just a rumor. But they don't specifically say what rumor it is. I can't remember it being mentioned in an earlier episode but I could have of course forgotten it. Is it known what rumor they were referring to?

Comment: You might wana look into [answer on similar question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/55445/1190) from Movie and TV. Here it might get closed due to future work rule.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can only speculate until anything is shown, which most likely won't happen in S06E09; I suspect the fireworks will be reserved for the (extra-long) season finale. But

- going by Qyburn's words:

  > "Your Grace... that old rumor you told me about."

  (note the "old"),
- looking at what is said next:

  > Qyburn: My little birds investigated.
  >
  > Cersei: And? Was it just a rumor or something more?
  >
  > Qyburn: More. Much more.

  (with the "more" suggesting to me that he's talking about the volume of something),
- and looking at the context (Cersei looking for ways to defeat the Faith Militant),

I can only think of one thing: **wildfire**.

There's a lot of it [beneath the capital city](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wildfire) (quoting from the Wikia):

> While convalescing at Harrenhal, Jaime Lannister reveals to Brienne of
>   Tarth that the real reason he killed Mad King Aerys II Targaryen is
>   because he was planning on burning the entire capital city to ashes
>   with wildfire, rather than let it fall to the rebels. When it began to
>   appear that the rebels would win the war, **the Mad King had his
>   pyromancers hide caches of wildfire all over King's Landing - under
>   the Great Sept of Baelor**, under the slums of Flea Bottom, under
>   houses, stables, taverns, and even under the Red Keep itself.

There's a bit of fore-warning in Jaime's words elsewhere in the episode, in his conversation with Edmure Tully:

> I suppose all mothers do, but Catelyn and Cersei, there's a fierceness
>   you don't often see. **They'd do anything to protect their babies.** Start
>   a war. **Burn cities to ash.** Free their worst enemies. The things we do
>   for love.

---

In "The Bear and the Maiden Fair", an episode from the third season (S03E07), [Jaime also hinted at the disaster he averted](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bear_and_the_Maiden_Fair_(episode)):

The relevant part:

> Qyburn: How many men have you killed, my lord?
>
> Jaime: I don't know.
>
> Qyburn: 50? 100? Countless.
>
> Jaime: Countless has a nice ring to it.
>
> Qyburn: And how many lives have you saved?
>
> Jaime: Half a million. The population of King's Landing.

---

Also note Tyrion's words to Daenerys in [S06E09, "Battle of the Bastards"](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Bastards):

> You once told me you knew what your father was. Did you know his plans for King's Landing when the Lannister armies were at his gates? Probably not. Well, he told my brother and Jaime told me. **He had caches of wildfire hidden under the Red Keep, the Guildhalls, the Sept of Baelor,** all the major thoroughfares. He would have burned every one of his citizens. The loyal ones and the traitors. Every man, woman, and child. That's why Jaime killed him.

---

In "The Winds of Winter", the season six finale (S06E10), we learn what rumors Qyburn and Cersei referred to:

> Ser Gregor Clegane prevents King Tommen from leaving the royal palace to attend the trial of Ser Loras Tyrell and Cersei Lannister in the Great Sept of Baelor. Queen Margaery Tyrell, Lord Mace Tyrell, and Ser Kevan Lannister are already there amongst many spectators, as well as the High Sparrow. 
>  
>  Finally the Sparrows bring Ser Loras in. After his trial is done, Lancel tells the High Sparrow that Cersei has yet to leave the Red Keep, so the High Sparrow asks him to go retrieve her. As Lancel is walking out, **one of the "little birds" lures him away into the area below the Sept. There, Lancel discovers a cache of wildfire about to be set off.**
>  
>  Margaery, realizing something is very wrong with the fact that neither Cersei nor Tommen are at the trial, confronts the High Sparrow. She tells him that it's a trap, but he does not listen. Margaery tells everyone in the Sept they need to leave immediately, but the Faith Militant prevent anyone from exiting. **Lancel does not make it to the wildfire in time, and the Sept explodes, killing everyone inside and outside of it as well as levelling most of the surrounding area.**

This recap of the events is largely based on the one available in [the episode's Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Winds_of_Winter).

Comment: Has it been explicitly mentioned that this was the rumor or it is just speculation? (Haven't watched the said episode so just asking).

Comment: Off the top of my head, It could be Tyrion's presence in Meereen. Tywin had asked Varys to dispatch little birds to Meereen in season 4 I think.

Comment: Ah haven't watched the episode yet (Will do tonight) therefore just relying on info here.  You should probably add the exact dialogue and your reasoning to make things clear. Cheers

Comment: Didn't they know about the wildfire (or at least Tyrion did) before the battle of the Blackwater?

Comment: Although in the books Cersei burned down the Tower of the Hand... so actually this does seem to fit.

Comment: @Skooba Yes, that knowledge is the only weak link, but I attribute that to bad writing. And that the little birds investigated this is also kinda ridiculous. In the end we won't know for sure until the end of this season...

Comment: Personally I'm not convinced by this answer. This is speculation and you said it yourself we won't know for sure until the end of the season. Therefore I won't accept this answer until we do know for sure, either by the show telling us or by other reliable sources.

Comment: I'd like to see either more evidence of this or a disclaimer that this is speculation. Because I could just as easily write an answer saying that the rumor is that Sansa has an army, or Dany isn't with her army, or the Greyjoys are sailing to Meereen and it would be just as legitimate of an answer. Why would Qyborn need to investigate something that was public knowledge a couple seasons ago (Battle of the Blackwater)?

Comment: @BCdotWEB there are other old rumors... For example, it could be that Rhaegar's son escaped (Aegon), Ned Starks bastard isn't Ned Starks bastard,  the Wall is a sleeping ice dragon, or hundreds of other rumors and legends.

Comment: There is Wildfire hidden inside the Wall. Bran wargs back in time and becomes 'Bran the builder', filling the wall with Wildfire. He Wargs as far into the future as possible, into the Mad King, who is actually screaming 'Burn the Wall!', not 'Burn them all!'. It's True. Georgie-Boy told me when he was drunk. Fire is the only thing that will defeat white walkers, and that's why it's called 'a Song of Ice and Fire'.

Comment: I like this theory. On one hand, it would give more meaning to sort-of random flashback about Mad King Bran was heaving. On the other hand, city full of Wildfire was the reason Jamie is a kingslayer, I think he would disclose this reason to Cersei (meaning it wouldn't be a rumor to her).

Comment: After seeing the finale I guess this is the intended answer. Although I'm still very surprised that you got it right. For me the answer wasn't really that obvious. Perhaps you had a little birdy telling you this haha

Comment: @IvoBeckers It was simple logic, based on what the show has told us. GoT has repeatedly shown in recent seasons that once it goes off-book, the results are usually disappointing and unsurprising. This was already pretty "advanced" compared to for instance what happened to Arya in previous episodes.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Maybe you would like to edit this answer to confirm that it was indeed wildfire in light of the events of s06e10?